# Default value returned by a class

Tags: c#, wpf, class, properties, tostring

I created a small custom class in c# to store the data for a playing card:

```
public class Card
    {
        public string suit { get; set; }
        public int number { get; set; }
        public string val
        {
            get
            {
                return number+" of "+suit;
            }
        }
    }
```

If a had a variable of type `Card`, and just printed `card.toString()`, it would print the namespace, window name, and class name. Is there a way I can have the value `val` print out just by referencing `card`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`override`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) keyword.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return number+" of "+suit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just have to override the [`ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) method (from `Object`).

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return val;
}
```

This also the default value you see in the Visual Studio debugger when inspecting an object.

Thanks to this overload, some methods (like `String.Format`, `Console.Write`, `Console.WriteLine`, ...) will use this new string representation without calling ToString yourself.

```
Console.WriteLine(card);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
Console.WriteLine(card.ToString());
```

That will be equivalent (after the override) to:

```
Console.WriteLine(card.val);
```

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it is the only one (as of this writing) that includes both code and an explanation.

Comment: its `object` not `Object` though.

Comment: @Aniket There is no difference between _object_ and _Object_

Comment: @CédricBignon Great, Thanks. There isn't a way just return that value without even using ToString(), is there?

Comment: @JesusSqueegee You can get _card.val_. I don't really understand your question.

Comment: @JesusSqueegee In fact it depends on how you want to use this value. For exemple if you want to use _Console.WriteLine(...)_ you can use directly _Console.WriteLine(card)_ (it will automatically call _card.ToString_ to get the string representation of your _Card_ instance. Same for _String.Format_ and some other UI methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Card
{
    public string suit { get; set; }
    public int number { get; set; }
    public string val
    {
        get
        {
            return number+" of "+suit;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return val;
    }


}
```